# Django Class Based View use @cache_page

Tags: python, django

I want to add `@cache_page` to a class based view however because of the way I have my url `url(r'^/(?P<shortcut>coming-soon)$', MovieList.as_view(), name='movie_list_coming_soon'),` it brings an error MovieList has no .as_view

The class MovieList is:

```
class MovieList(ListView):
    model = Movie
    paginate_by = 20
    context_object_name = 'movies'
    category = None
    venue = None
    date = None
    slug_level = ""

    def get_queryset(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        qs = Movie.objects.filter(visible=True,).order_by('-hot', '-showing', 'name')
        if self.request.mobile:
            self.template_name = 'mobile/movies.html'
        if self.kwargs.get('category', None):
            slugs = self.kwargs['category'].strip('/').split('/')
            self.category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slugs[-1])
            category_ids = [c.id for c in self.category.get_child_categories()]
            category_ids.append(self.category.id)
            qs = qs.filter(categories__in=category_ids)
        if self.kwargs.get('venue', None):
            .....
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?